# Why is a callback inside React's setState causing blocking?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in my code:

```
this.setState({newState}, function(){ this.focus });
```

However, when I include the callback, it blocks everything else. Is this this right way of having a function callback inside setState?

Comment: This is the right way to do something after setState on the face of it. Can you elaborate on the problem you are seeing? It's also possible that `this` is undefined in your example as the function context may not be bound properly.

Comment: Very strange, but I figured out what the issue is ..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, having the state passed in as an object, versus explicitly defining the state variables is what's causing this blocking.

Wrong:

```
let newState = {
   var1: true,
   var2: false
};
this.setState({newState}, function(){ this.focus });
```

Right:

```
this.setState({var1: true, var2: false}, function(){ this.focus });
```

Comment: Right because `{newState}` is a new ES6 feature that is shorthand for `{newState: newState}`. Try this instead: `this.setState(newState, function(){ this.focus });` Note how `newState` is no longer surrounded in braces.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further context I would suggest `this` is undefined and the error is getting swallowed up. Try this:

```
this.setState(newState, () => this.focus());
```